# Collapse posts titles menu by year and by month

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm totally lost at this problem.

> Display years, then on clicking a year expand showing any months with
>   posts in them, then on clicking a month display all the post titles in
>   that month as links to the actual post.

I'm very new on javascript but i need to solve this problem fast as i can.  On this "problem" i'm sitting over 4 hours.
This is site where i need to do this type of menu: http://baltkojyterima.site90.com/

And this is site where you can see what exactly i need : http://www.thewebsitedeveloper.co.nz/tempProject/nzca-wordpress/news-menu-test/

```html
<aside>
  <div class="aside-left-menu">
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     
     
       
      </div><!--end post-->

    <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br> In this block i need to do this(i described) type of menu. </br>
  </div>
HERE I NEED JAVASCRIPT CODE>
```

Thank you guys for any help you will give!

------------------ EDIT -------------------

Thanks, but problem has been solved. I will just start learn working with jquery. :)

Comment: Please show your code and attempts to troubleshoot.

Comment: I inserted that code i need to edit. If you will need other files, say.

Comment: Can you give us more info about your db structure? Is this date info stored together with posts, how do you match them?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most simple way that I could come up with. It's not even near perfect, but I hope it can help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/Arministrator/dt0f387t/1/

```
$(".clickthis").click(function(){
 var ct = $(this).children("ul");
 ct.show();})
```

Comment: It's too simple way. You see, i never know when new post is writen so i need to take data from data base, then using that data distribute my posts titles in months... Sorry, bad english :)